# Directly copy a link from a stream

Tags: javascript

I have been asked if its possible to directly extract a stream link from a website.
I remember being able to do this with a video but am not able to find a direct link to a stream using the same inspect elements method.

The stream link I'm trying to get is: http://www.jagobd.com/al-dawah-tv

It occurred to me that the reason it might not be possible is that its illegal or the site does not want me to be able to do this. If this is the issue I won't need any further help since I don't want to breach policy or law.

Thanks in advance,

Sven

Comment: Regarding legality depends on where you live (but in general it isn't ?). But no, all stream links are in the webpage directly or retrieved later with javascript.

Comment: Also check the network tab in the developer console: There is a chunks request sent : https://nl.jagobd.com:444/c2VydmVyX4RpbEU9Mi8xNy8yMDE0GIDU6RgzQ6NTAgdEoaeFzbF92YWxIZTO0U0ezN1IzMyfvcGVMZEJCTEFWeVN3PTOmdFsaWRtaW51aiPhnPTI/dawah-eu.stream/live-orgin/dawah-eu.stream/chunks.m3u8?nimblesessionid=10763867&wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MS8yMS8yMDE5IDE6MTU6MTcgUE0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT0rQkh5TFpWNTh2STJFcnpIMzJROUZnPT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTU=

Comment: you can find it with `document.querySelector('iframe')​` and src is direct link to your stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the stream link can be extracted, but it's probably not going to be useful. In the case of http://www.jagobd.com/al-dawah-tv, the embedded `<iframe>` source is https://tvs.jagobd.com/embed.php?u=Dawahtv&vw=700&vh=480&autoplay=true.

However, trying to visit that link directly results in a redirect.

I would imagine that the places hosting the stream are paying for the right to stream content on their platform. To ensure payment, the server hosting the iframe likely checks the origin that requests are coming from and ensure that there is a paid account associated with that origin. Otherwise, the server can respond with a redirect.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this situation is much more clear to me now!